# Javascript function is not triggered for a div thats loaded with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

I'm using [Infinite Scroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) plugin for pagination. As the `div#stream` is loaded with Ajax, this function `$('#stream').infinitescroll` is not getting Triggered.

```
$(function() {
  $('#stream').infinitescroll({
    navSelector     : ".paginate:last",
    nextSelector    : "a.paginate:last",
    dataType        : 'json',
    appendCallback  : false,
    path: "someurl"
  }, function(json, opts){
    alert("json Fetched..")
  });
});
```

Any Idea how to make it work?

Comment: can you explain about whats happening? output of console/errors?

Comment: No errors. The function was not triggered as I have added it inside document.ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As the div#stream is loaded with Ajax, this function $('#stream').infinitescroll is not getting Triggered.

make sure you call the `.infinitescroll({` after the div#stream is loaded in the document..

```
$.ajax({
 ...
success:function(){
   //your codes which appends #stream 
   $('#stream').infinitescroll({
      navSelector     : ".paginate:last",
      nextSelector    : "a.paginate:last",
      dataType        : 'json',
      appendCallback  : false,
      path: "someurl"
    }, function(json, opts){
      alert("json Fetched..")
    });
  }
});
```

you need to call the methods again when an element is dynamically added. calling it in document.ready will be of no help since when the document is ready the `#stream` div might not be present in the document when this method is called

Comment: Works now :) Thank you Bipen :)